# Can't get images from storage laravel 5

Tags: php, image, laravel

Hey so i'm trying to put my images into a slideshow i have on my index.
the images are saved on `storage/app` , and then the rest of the path i retrive from my database.

I managed to output the correct path on the `<img src>` tag, and the title gets output like its supposed to, but the image won't.

I send and array from the controller and then cycle through it on my view:

Controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $projects = Project::all()->take(4);
    return view('index' , compact('projects'));

}
```

Index view

```
@foreach($projects as $project)
{{$storagePath  = Storage::disk('local')->getDriver()->getAdapter()->getPathPrefix()}}
<li><img src="{{$storagePath.$project->fetchMedia->first()->public_name}}"    title=" {{$project->name}}"></li>
        @endforeach
```

The HTML output is the correct path : "/home/vagrant/project/storage/app/projects/Domaa6.jpg"

but it doesn't show the image.

I already tried to use the HTML::image helper but had no success either.

is there a way to get it working like it is or do i need to create a new controller to manipulate my images?

The `fetchMedia` is the function on my model that returns my Media.

```
public function fetchMedia()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Media');
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you are trying to do is not possible in the storage directory but possible only in public directory, also exposing the path or URL to your laravel storage directory creates some vulnerability and its bad practice

**However there is a way to workaround it:**

First, you need an Image package to generate the image dynamically when a certain route is referenced, I recommend **[intervention/image](http://image.intervention.io/)** which is has many methods that makes image manage a breeze.

**To achieve this take the following steps:**

**1. Install Intervention Image:**

*Add Intervention Image to yourr composer.json and the do `composer update`*

```
"require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "laravel/framework": "5.1.*",
        "intervention/image": "2.*",
        "intervention/imagecache": "2.*"

        .....
```

*In the $providers array add the service providers for this package.*

```
'Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider'
```

*Add the facade of this package to the $aliases array.*

`'Image' => 'Intervention\Image\Facades\Image`'

*Configure Intervention Image in Laravel 5*

```
$ php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProviderLaravel5"
```

*Publish configuration in Laravel 4*

```
$ php artisan config:publish intervention/image
```

For more installation detail https://github.com/Intervention/image

After you install intervention/image you can do something like this:

`Image::make($path=storage_path('stock-photos/image1.jpg'));`

**2. Setup a route that will handle image requests**

```
Route::get('stock-photos/{image}', function($image){

    //do so other checks here if you wish

    if(!File::exists( $image=storage_path("stock-photos/{$image}") )) abort(404);

    return Image::make($image)->response('jpg'); //will ensure a jpg is always returned
});
```

**3. Then later in the view you can do:**

```
@foreach($projects as $project)
    <li>
        <img src="{{url('stock-photos/'. $project->fetchMedia->first()->public_name)}}" title="{{$project->name}}">
    </li>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Don't you think it will put load on server?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately I can't comment on Digitlimit's post (as I'm not high enough in reputation yet) but their response worked for me but with one change. Instead of returning the `Image::make($image)` I used the `response()` method instead as this seemed to generate the header content for me. So for example

```
Route::get('stock-photos/{image}', function($image){

if(!File::exists( $image=storage_path("stock-photos/{$image}") )) abort(404);

$returnImage = Image::make($image);

return $returnImage->response();
});
```

Hope that helps others with a similar issue.

Comment: I thought you can comment with with 49 reps? I think if you complete your profile or so you can comment. Intervention Image has many methods and response() is good as well and I omitted it by error. will edit my answer. thanks. one up vote for you

Comment: Thank you for the one up vote as now I can comment :) but your answer was great and worked a charm for me so thank you.

Answer (score 0):

when displaying images you don't need to reference the file path. What gets into the `img` tag is URL to the image you want to display. So, in you case this would be

```
@foreach($projects as $project)
    {{$storagePath  = Storage::disk('local')->getDriver()->getAdapter()->getPathPrefix()}}
    <li><img src="/{{$project->fetchMedia->first()->public_name}}"    title=" {{$project->name}}"></li>
@endforeach
```

But. this won't work either as the resources that you make `http` requests to should be publicaly accessable. (like css, js-scripts, images). With this being said, you need to store you images in a different location, public folder is the perfect place for this. If you save your images for example in `public/images/projects` then in your view you would reference them like this

```
<img src="/images/projects/{{$project->fetchMedia->first()->public_name}}" />
```

Comment: @AndrewMalinnkovi had it working on the public folder the exact same way you said, but my client requested the images must be stored on storage/app/ImageName, thats why im struggling.

Comment: your client will be disappointed but this can't be accomplished. Server root is the public folder and everything that beyond that is not accessible for the browser. You can manipulate the image however you want on server side, but not "front end". You could suggest your client store resources on Amazon s3 server, which is quite nice and much more flexible rather than keeping them locally

Comment: Yes, it is misleading as it implies the storage folder is the preferred easy way to store files [link]http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/filesystem#basic-usage

Answer (score 0):

Although I've been using Laravel for about 2 years now, I've just started to process image uploads with it very recently (using version 5.3.16). Troubleshooting image processing lead me to this Stack Overflow post... The original accepted answer pretty much solved the issues I was having, with some minor changes as below:

```
Route::get('images/books/{book_id}/{image}', function($book_id, $image){

    $storagePath  = Storage::disk('public')->getDriver()->getAdapter()->getPathPrefix();
    $imageFilePath = $storagePath . "images/books/{$book_id}/{$image}";
    if(!File::exists($imageFilePath)) abort(404);

    return Image::make($imageFilePath)->response();
});
```

In this particular example, I want to retrieve a particular uploaded image for a book. For the given book, I have created a directory which matches the book's I.D, and have uploaded the image into there.

To retrieve the image, I first get the public storage directory. This is usually defined in the 'filesystems.php' config file in config/app directory. My example is below (omitted extras not needed for this answer):

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Filesystem Disk
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the default filesystem disk that should be used
    | by the framework. A "local" driver, as well as a variety of cloud
    | based drivers are available for your choosing. Just store away!
    |
    | Supported: "local", "ftp", "s3", "rackspace"
    |
    */

    'default' => 'local',

    .
    .
    .

    'disks' => [

        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],

    ],

];
```

The rest of the route info follows the same pattern as the first accepted answer. Rendering the image also follows the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

storage_path()
The storage_path function returns the fully qualified path to your application's storage directory. You may also use the storage_path function to generate a fully qualified path to a given file within the storage directory:

```
 $path = storage_path();

 $path = storage_path('app/file.txt');
```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-storage-path

Answer (score 0):

1. From laravel root directory remove storage folder from public/storage
2. After that run php artisan storage:link
3. In your view now you can display image using the below code
   image) }}">
   your link should be like: