# Getting an image to render with php

Tags: php, image, laravel, image-processing

To keep it simple, I'm trying to display an image using php to help *try* and prevent any kind of a security loophole. I have the image being read through a php script and I am wanting to render it, so instead of going to `http://example.com/path/to/uploads/dir/image.jpg` I want to have the user be able to go to `http://example.com/path/to/script/image1` and have them be able to see the image.

This way I can hide the image path  (`http://example.com/path/to/uploads/dir/`) outside my document root (to where it can't be outright accessed by the domain path). So if the path to the domain was `/path/to/public_html/` then I want the images uploaded to `/path/to/uploads/` so you can't navigate to the uploads dir when surfing my domain.

My issue is the image I have been *trying* to render, won't render and I'm unsure as to why. The MD5 checksums are the same, and the HTTP headers are similar. The [direct path](http://dev.austinkregel.com/uploads/2015/june/11/wERfjO.jpg) to the image, compared to the [desired path](http://dev.austinkregel.com/api/v1/titan/image/1) to the image.

I am using Laravel as a framework / backbone, but I don't think that matters to much, and my code to render the image is below

```
public function getImage($id){
  $img = TitanImage::findOrFail($id);
//  header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
//  header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($img->path));
//  header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
//  echo file_get_contents($img->path);
  $file = $img->path;
  $type = 'image/jpeg';
  header('Content-Type:'.$type);
  header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
  readfile($file);
//  exit();
  return;
}
```

I also used [webconfs](http://www.webconfs.com/http-header-check.php) to check the headers of both of the desired image endpoints.

## Edit 1

In regards to one of the comments about the `intervention/image` package, I changed my code and I still get the same result; however, the content-length has changed, it's gotten longer.

```
public function getImage($id){
  $img = TitanImage::findOrFail($id);
//  header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
//  header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($img->path));
//  header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
  $file = $img->path;
  return Image::make(trim($file,' '))->response();
}
```

## Edit 2

In this edit, @Digitlimit mentioned checking to see if the image exists. This is my current code.

```
public function getImage($id){
  $img = TitanImage::findOrFail($id);
  $file = $img->path;
  if(file_exists($file))
    return Image::make($file)->response('jpg');
  else
    return 'File doesnt exist';
}
```

I also did test to see what would happen if I were to just return `$file` instead of the `Image::make` instance, I get the proper path, ie. when I go to SSH into the server and `cd` to the path minus the image name the path exists and has permissions. When I do the `ls -la` command it lists the image and it also has the proper permissions.

Comment: wrong terminology. "behind my domain". it should be "outside of my document root".

Comment: why not use Intervention Image its awesome. See this answer to similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30875139/cant-get-images-from-storage-laravel-5/30882720#30882720

Comment: @Digitlimit I updated my code and I still haven't had a change, I also updated the question.

Comment: Have you installed intervention image? If yes you need to create a route. Please also specify were your image is located

Comment: I followed the instructions on the intervention.io website, I created a route that retreived the image based upon the path stored in the database, which is the code in my question. I am making the image, and returning a response.

Comment: I have checked the URL you gave. It *is* a JPEG, **except** that it has a space immediately before and apparently a carriage return after:

    convert: Unsupported marker type 0x0a `test.jpg' @ warning/jpeg.c/JPEGErrorHandler/319

Comment: @Iserni Do you know of anyway to correct this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is working - the problem is it's sending *extra* information. The file **is** there, it **is** found, it **is** being sent. The link to your image returns:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 17 Jun 2015 22:52:03 GMT
Server: Apache
Connection: close
Content-Type: image/jpeg
```

But the subsequent output is **wrong**:

```
00000050  3a 20 63 6c 6f 73 65 0d  0a 43 6f 6e 74 65 6e 74  |: close..Content|
00000060  2d 54 79 70 65 3a 20 69  6d 61 67 65 2f 6a 70 65  |-Type: image/jpe|
00000070  67 0d 0a 0d 0a 20 ff d8  ff e1 19 57 45 78 69 66  |g.... .....WExif|
                         ^^
                           `this 20 here, before the ff d8 ff of JPEG.
```

So this code (being only responsible for the JPEG part) is OK.

```
public function getImage($id){
  $img    = TitanImage::findOrFail($id);
  $file   = $img->path;
  if (file_exists($file)) {
      return Image::make($file)->response('jpg');
  }
  else {
    return "File doesn't exist";
  }
}
```

The extra space at the beginning of the data stream *might* come from some PHP file with an extra whitespace before the opening `<?php` tag, or maybe after the closing tag.

For the latter, it is recommended that you *do not* close the `<?php` tag, i.e. you never include the "?>" sequence.

For the former, try

```
public function getImage($id) {
    return "*** is there a space before the asterisks?";
}
```

and observe the returned HTML. Unless the error is in TitanImage, which I believe unlikely, you should see the same space before the asterisks that is sent before the JPEG image. The file where the `getImage()` function is defined is a likely suspect.

Otherwise, you can run "grep" to find PHP files that do *not* start with `<?php`. You can modify this [shameless plug](https://superuser.com/a/927866/166800) by adding the `-v` flag to `grep`.

Comment: I will try this once I get back to work on the project tomorrow and let you know the out come.

Comment: I just double checked every file for the titan project and what do you know. There was a space in my routes file just before `<?php` I really want to thank you @Iserni.

Comment: You're welcome. If you knew how many times it happened to me... :-D

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed intervention image then do this:

```
public function getImage($id){
  $img = TitanImage::findOrFail($id);
  $file = $img->path;
  return Image::make($file)->response('jpg');
}
```

Edited:
I tested this on my project and it works perfectly:

**Route:**

```
Route::get('/api/v1/titan/image/{id}',function($id){
    return \Image::make(storage_path("/images/$id.jpg"))->response('jpg');
});
```

**Image location in my project:**

[image]

**Output when I visit URL:**http://laravel.dev/api/v1/titan/image/1

[image]

**Chrome Element Inspection**
[image]

[image]

Comment: Thats exactly what I'm doing. In mine I'm just making sure that there are no spaces.

Comment: The image path is either wrong or not valid. I will include code to check if file exists. Also ensure you have GD extension enabled

Comment: I edited my question to include checking to see if the file exists. I also confirmed that the GD extension is enabled.

Comment: Please may I see the output you are getting?

Comment: What output would you like?

Comment: The code in your view for displaying image and also the error message you are getting

Comment: The code for viewing everything is in my question. I made a link to [my image](http://austinkregel.com/dev/api/v1/titan/image/1) and a link to the [desired image](http://dev.austinkregel.com/uploads/2015/june/11/wERfjO.jpg). The desired image is showing the image, where as my image isn't. I don't have any error message, I'm just not seeing my image.

Comment: Cannot visit links because am using mobile app. Its always good to include all relevant code in your question rather than pastebin or external link so errors can be spotted easily

Comment: What are you talking about? My code is in my question. I am using the mobile application as well and I don't have an issue with getting on the links. The links are to my website. They are the links to the images not to code.

Comment: Am sorry, I was asking for your HTML code, but I can see that you are accessing the image directly. I just visited the links through my PC and I can see the dynamic image is not showing. I will try to create this on my system with exactly same image and see why its not working. Am sure we can me this work.

Comment: @Austin Kregel please see edited question. Please do a `dd($file);` to see if  the file path is correct

Comment: If you look on the second part of my answer you will see I have already compared the `$file` variable to the desired path. They match perfectly.

Comment: please could you set `$file = storage_path("/to/uploaded/image/filename");` and try? just to verify